# Bilinear form matrix coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I don't know how to solve this problem - I have to transform the coordinates of a bilinear form that has matrix 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & -2 \\
        2 & -2 & 3 \\
        -2 & 3 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
in base 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -3 & 1 & 0 \\
        5 & -2 & 3 \\
        2 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
To matrix of the same bilinear form in the base
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        2 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
How do I do it? Should there be scalar products of the base vectors in the matrix(but then I do not understand what is there the first base for) or can I just find a transition matrix from one base to the other and just multipy it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need the change of basis matrix $P$ whose columns are the coefficients of the *new* basis vectors when you express them as linear combinations of the *old*. I'll let you figure out how to get that from the two matrices directly. Then the expression for the bilinear form in the new basis should be $P^TAP$, where its matrix representation in the old basis is $A$. (To convince yourself of this, remember that the coordinate vector of a vector $x$ with respect to the new basis will be $x'=Px$. So $x^TAy = (Px')^TA'(Py') = \dots$.)